# What does the word "stock" mean in the word "Stock Media Product" on an agreement of 3Dmodel?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are many meanings in the word "stock", but it's hard for me to figure out which one it is in the web dictionary.

The web dictionary:
https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stock

And here's the definition of “Stock Media Product” in the document:

> “Stock Media Product” is the collection of one or more digital files, packaged in the form of a product on the Site that can be identified by a product ID, and that is uploaded by you, or otherwise made available to you, for Purchase on the Site. A Stock Media Product may include 3D models, texture maps, motion captures, photographs, imagery, application and plug-in software, materials and shaders, shapes and vector graphics, training materials, building components, sound effects, stock music, and videos. Additionally, a Stock Media Product may include a number of individual files of different file formats to make it easier for Customers to work in a variety of software applications (such as 3ds Max, Maya, and Cinema 4D), and may also include other files (such as jpeg images used for texturing), and images or other files that are used for promotional purposes. For Customers and their use in Creations, this definition also includes derivative and intermediary files used for that purpose.

from:
https://blog.turbosquid.com/royalty-free-license/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of media, the word stock has a slightly more specific use than just merchandise or materials that are available (in stock).

The term [stock photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_photography), for example, is used to contrast with photos taken as one-offs: for example a newspaper photographer might take a photograph of an event so it can be printed in the paper; or a wedding photographer will take photos of a couples wedding specifically for them. These are not stock photographs.

Stock media, on the other hand, are photos, videos, artwork, etc that are created to be sold multiple times, to anyone who wants them, rather than as records of a specific event or thing.

They are usually sold with a license specifying what they can be used for, and what the payment terms are for various uses. (There are also public domain and royalty-free media available.)

Comment: Great explanation, I've learned a lot. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, **stock** as in **Stock Media Product** is a legally defined entity [Company](https://blog.turbosquid.com/royalty-free-license/) by said company in your question. The **stock** this company sells are collections or baskets of digital artistry and are copyright protected.  The best dictionary definition of stock (you nicely provided a link and demonstrated *your* research) in this situation would be 'merchandise' for sale

This one company has 7 baskets.  There many 'digital warehouses' that package digital right protected work and sell for public consumption.

[image: digital baskets for sale]